# How to create barcode using php with content type EAN-13

Tags: php, barcode

I'm try to create barcode in php with the type of EAN-13.

But my php barcode haven't take `letters` or `variables` (e.g, ' ','c','^' and etc.). It only take `numbers`.

For example, If I am generating barcode successfully for the string `234567890987`. But I can't generate barcode for the string `NO-289898989`.

If any possible to generate barcode for both variable and constants usin php?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use both variables and constants. But they still may only have arabic numbers 0 to 9, as per https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/ean-upc

Comment: @AmigoJack, I see your reference link. But it is only have a type EAN.

Comment: The page that @AmigoJack linked, says *EAN-13: Capacity: 13 numeric*. Numeric means numbers (0-9)...

Comment: @FZs. Ok. #AmigoJack says EAN_13 accept both variable and constants. If any possible are there.

Comment: I don't have too much knowledge in this topic, that was just a quick remark...

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the words `variable` and `constant` - they're bound to the programming/scripting language, not to the content of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application requires alphabetic characters you should be looking at Code 128. You should only be using EAN 18 or EAN 8 if you are labeling products for  consumption at a retail store. If that is the case, the data you place inside the symbol will be given to you by the retailer, and it will not be alphabetic.

If, on the other hand, you are labeling items for inventory control, you should use Code 128.

If you are placing large amounts of data onto a paper medium, you should use QR Code or PDF417.

Comment: I say EAN 18 above. Should be EAN 13.